# Problema con acceso web, pagina moodle

Tags: linux, moodle

estoy tratando de instalar un servicio moodle en un linux centos, pero cuando trato de ingresar por la web obtengo este error.

```
 Invalid permissions detected when trying to create a directory. Turn debugging 
 on for further details.
```

Tengo esta variable en el config.php $CFG->directorypermissions = 0777; pero aun así tengo este problema, que podría ser?

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo de configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontre esto en los logs.

```
[Wed Dec 11 17:07:26.519572 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 25841] [client 
10.1.0.67:56836] PHP Warning:  
unlink(/var/www/moodledata/cache/core_component.php): Permission denied in 
/var/www/html/Sitios/Sal/html/Form/lib/classes/component.php on 
line 297
```

Comment: Intenta habilitar el debugging para obtener mas detalles. Por probablemente tiene que ver con los permisos de archivo de los directorios del proyecto, en este caso el servidor debe poder tener permiso de escritura.

Comment: Es decir, los permisos de la carpeta moodle que tengo dentro del document root del server web?

Comment: El equipo es linux o windows?

Comment: Es un linux centos 7

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo de configuracion

Comment: Intenta seteando los permisos de esa carpeta a 777 con chmod

Comment: Ahi tengo la confusion, podria setearlo en el directorio de mi proyecto, dentro del DocumentRoot o en el moodledata?

Comment: Dale prueba sin miedo, hasta que funcione si no funciona devuelvelo a los permisos que tenía para evitar problemas de seguridad.

Comment: No funciono con permisos 777 los deje como estaba a 755 en las carpetas y los archivos en 644

Comment: [Wed Dec 11 17:07:26.519572 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 25841] [client 
    10.1.0.67:56836] PHP Warning:  
    unlink(/var/www/moodledata/cache/core_component.php): Permission 
    denied in 
/var/www/html/Sitios/Sal/html/Form/lib/classes/component.php on 
line 297